# Identify IP of the client causing high interface usage on uplink port

Tags: cisco, ip-address, interface

**Background:**

We are observing a high interface load (spikes up to 1G) on a WAN (dedicated link) uplink port of a Cisco switch. How can we find the IP of the client that is causing this high load?

I have done some research before asking: I have looked at NetFlow manual, but could not find any examples of `matches` relevant to my problem. Also, we don't have a network monitoring host to send the traffic to. I have also come across IP Accounting, but it is deprecated for our switch.

This is a new install.

Our hardware is Cisco Nexus 5672UP, 7.3(0)N1(1)

Could someone please suggest a set of commands (potentially involving NetFlow in cached mode) to get from *an interface name* to *a table of IP addresses with their transient bandwidth usages*?

Comment: You should be able to monitor excessive usage on your firewall.

Comment: @Zac67, thank you, but on that segment of network there isn't a firewall

Comment: OK. You now have me confused. You claim it is Cisco IOS, but it is really a Nexus switch that does not use IOS, it uses NX-OS. Those are very different things.

Comment: @RonMaupin, apologies, I have corrected the question - IOS is the switch that is on the other side of the link, but it's an old Catalyst and it doesn't even have ip accounting. I have been advised that we will be better off focusing on the Nexus that is closer to the stations potentially generating this traffic, and it would have visibility of their IP addresses. So it's a Nexus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Netflow is supported on the 5600's but NXOS doesn't provide the same local information that IOS does (ex: no `show ip cache flow` equivalent).

You'll need to collect the Netflow on an external host and run something like a top-talkers query.  There are a ton of commercial and open source tools for Netflow analysis but bear in mind that the 5600 only supports *sampled* Netflow.  This isn't a big deal for your use case and most modern Netflow analyzers support sampling.

Comment: Thank you! I have accepted the answer. Any chance of you providing a set of commands (like the question mentions), so that I can see an example of how to configure matches for this particular problem? I don't want to make them too broad, but instead see a good example for configuring them to relay the minimum required metrics.

Answer (score 0):

There might be some other solutions to your problem. Netflow is one way. Another keyword could be "ip accounting" but you have also to read the manuals. For a quick look and if you have the possibillity to configure a monitor/span port, you can use an ordinary laptop with wireshark to get the information needed.

Comment: Thank you, that is a good piece of advice. I was hoping to find a sequence of NetFlow configuration commands (for local cache, not sending to monitoring server). Something that would keep only the essnetial bits of information that we need to get the answer